# Why is declval present in a mangled symbol name?

Tags: c++, abi

I was playing around with GCC (4.9.2) abi::__cxa_demangle and I got to a case where it couldn't demangle a specific symbol name.

That symbol is:

```
_ZNK12DebugWrapperIR5TestClsE5getIdIIEEEDTcldtcl7declvalIS1_EEL_ZNKS0_5getIdEvEspfp_EEDpOT_
```

I'm surprise to see "declval" in there.

That specific function is defined using this macro:

```
template <typename WrappedType>
class DebugWrapper
{
private:
WrappedType VALUE;
std::string NAME;
mutable std::string CALLER;

public:
...
#define WRAP_CONST_FUNCTION(name, enterLogging, exitLogging)                                    \
        template <typename ...Args>                                                             \
        auto name(Args&&... args) const -> decltype(std::declval<WrappedType>().name(args...))  \
        {                                                                                       \
                                                                                            \
            struct dummy                                                                        \
            {                                                                                   \
                const char* const FUNCTION = nullptr;                                           \
                const std::string& CALLER;                                                      \
                const WrappedType& VALUE;                                                       \
                                                                                                \
                dummy(  const char* const input,                                                \
                        const std::string& caller,                                              \
                        const WrappedType& value):                                              \
                    FUNCTION(input), CALLER(caller), VALUE(value)                               \
                {                                                                               \
                    enterLogging;                                                               \
                }                                                                               \
                                                                                                \
                ~dummy()                                                                        \
                {                                                                               \
                    exitLogging;                                                                \
                }                                                                               \
            }dummy(#name, CALLER, VALUE);                                                       \
                                                                                                \
            return VALUE.name(args...);                                                         \
        }
        WRAP_CONST_FUNCTION(getId, <whatever>, <whatever>)
...
};
```

I also did a quick seach through the [itanium c++ abi spec](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) for declval but no result.

Why is it there ? and why can't abi::__cxa_demangle demangle it?

Comment: Why would it not be there? You aren't surprised by the `getId`, so I assume you do understand that sometimes, expressions need to be mangled including function names, and you have an unevaluated call to `declval` too.

Comment: getId should be there since it's the function name. std::declval on the other hand is only used to deduce the return type of the function at compile time. Why would it need to be present in the mangled name?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread. I did notice you use `getId` in return type, but I didn't notice you also used it as the function name. Yeah, the return type contains a call to the `declval` function, and the return type of a template function needs to be part of the mangled name to deal with overloads that differ only on return type. Will attempt to figure out a better way to word this to come up with an answer, if no one beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template functions need to have their return type appear in the mangled name because template functions can be overloaded on return type alone. A simpler example is

```
template <typename T> void f() { }
template <typename T> auto g() -> decltype(f<T>()) { }
inline void h() { }
int main() { g<int>(); h(); }
```

Compiling this and inspecting the output, I see:

```
$ g++ -c h.cc -std=c++11 && nm h.o | c++filt
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 W decltype ((f)()) g()
0000000000000000 W h()
```

You can see the return type there for `g`, but not for `h`. The fact that `h` is not a template function already means there cannot be another function `h` in the same namespace with the same parameters.

This is also why `getId` appears twice in your mangled name. One of those is the name itself, the other is coming from its appearance in the return type.

`declval` is not special here, which is why it's not called out in the C++ ABI. Any function, library or user, gets treated the same way.

As for why it won't demangle, it's hard to tell. A real code example that generates the mangled name in your question would help here, but the `5TestCls` looks wrong, as the number that precedes a name indicates the length, and I do get the impression that `TestCls` was supposed to be the full name. If that was indeed the name, then the demangling fails because the mangled name is invalid.

Based on the complete example, the one that you posted in the comments, I can come up with a reduced program, and it seems like it's the member access operator that's not handled properly by the demangler:

```
extern struct A { void f(); static void g(); } a;
template <typename...T> auto f(T...t) -> decltype(a.f(t...));
template <typename...T> auto g(T...t) -> decltype(A::g(t...));
int main() { f(); g(); }
```

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -c h.cc && nm h.o && nm -C h.o
0000000000000000 T main
                 U _Z1fIJEEDTcldtL_Z1aEL_ZN1A1fEvEspfp_EEDpT_
                 U _Z1gIJEEDTclL_ZN1A1gEvEspfp_EEDpT_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U _Z1fIJEEDTcldtL_Z1aEL_ZN1A1fEvEspfp_EEDpT_
                 U decltype (A::g({parm#1}...)) g<>()
```

The difference between `_Z1fIJEEDTcldtL_Z1aEL_ZN1A1fEvEspfp_EEDpT_` and `_Z1gIJEEDTclL_ZN1A1gEvEspfp_EEDpT_` is more apparent with some extra spacing:

```
_Z1fIJEEDTcldtL_Z1aEL_ZN1A1fEvEspfp_EEDpT_
_Z1gIJEEDTcl        L_ZN1A1gEvEspfp_EEDpT_
```

The only differences are `f` vs. `g`, and `dtL_Z1aE`.

The Itanium C++ ABI specifies that `x.y` is mangled as `dt <expression> <unresolved-name>`. Here, `<expression>` is `L_Z1aE`. That part looks right. That indicates the "mangled" (not really) name of the `a` global variable. But `<unresolved-name>` is `_ZN1A1fEvE`. That's wrong. That's right for the `decltype(A::g(t...))` version, where the left-most operand of the function call operator can be represented as a mangled name through the `<expr-primary> ::= L <mangled-name> E` production, but not for the `decltype(a.f(t...))` version. It would mean something like `A::f()`, but `<unresolved-name>` is not supposed to have namespace qualifiers unless they actually appear in the source code, and even then, only with a special prefix (`sr`). It also isn't supposed to have parameter info. The `<unresolved-name>` should just be `1f`.

If the corrected name is used, then the demangler can handle it:

```
$ c++filt <<< _Z1fIJEEDTcldtL_Z1aE1fspfp_EEDpT_              
decltype ((a.f)({parm#1}...)) f<>()
```

clang does generate the correct name, as can be seen on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dfec53f4560bc91) simply by changing `g++` to `clang++` in your command invocation. You may want to report this as a bug to the GCC developers.

Comment: I manually replace the original class name with TestCls. Anyway, here is a complete example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0426ccc1f7c0a21 (sadly it exceeds the size limit on coliru so you must compile it on your machine, please that the -rdynamic flag must be set)

Comment: @user1233963 Thanks. Even without actually running it, compiling it without linking, and then inspecting `nm`'s output filtered through `c++filt`, it cannot demangle the name either. This looks like a limitation of the current version of the demangler, and is probably worth further reducing and then reporting as a bug if you haven't reported it already. It doesn't indicate anything wrong on your end in your use of the demangler API. I'll attempt to manually demangle the name later, to check if the name is valid and the demangler has a bug, or the compiler generates a bad name.

Comment: @user1233963 It turns out it's not a bug in the demangler (or your use of it), but in GCC for wrongly mangling the name.